# Can't Cover @future REST Callout

Tags: apex, rest-api, code-coverage, callout, future

I have the following **trigger** and REST-callout **class** in a source org:

```
trigger SendOpp_Trigger on Opportunity (before insert) {
    for(Opportunity o : Trigger.new){
        SendOpportunity.createOpportunity(o.name, o.Account_External_Id__c, o.CloseDate, o.StageName);
    }
}


public class SendOpportunity {

    String clientId = '*****';
    String clientsecret ='*****';
    String username='fake@fake.com';
    String password = '*****';
    String accesstoken_url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
    String authurl = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize';

    public class deserializeResponse {

        public String id;
        public String access_token;

    }

    public String ReturnAccessToken(SendOpportunity Opp){

        String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='
        +clientSecret+'&username='+username+'&password='+password;

        Http h= new Http();
        HttpRequest req= new HttpRequest();
        req.setBody(reqbody);
        req.setMethod('POST'); 
        req.setEndpoint('https://na50.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');

        HttpResponse res=h.send(req);

        deserializeResponse resp1= (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),deserializeResponse.class);

        return resp1.access_token;
    }

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void createOpportunity(String oppName, String acctId, Date d, String stage){

        SendOpportunity opp1 = new SendOpportunity();

        String accessToken = opp1.ReturnAccessToken(opp1);

        if(accessToken!=null){

            String endPoint='https://na50.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Opportunity';             

            String jsonstr='{"Name":"'+ oppName +'","AccountId":"'+ acctId +'","CloseDate":"'+ String.valueOf(d) +'","StageName":"'+ stage +'"}';

            Http h2 = new Http();
            HttpRequest req2 = new HttpRequest();
            req2.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + accessToken);
            req2.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            req2.setHeader('accept','application/json');
            req2.setBody(jsonstr);
            req2.setMethod('POST');
            req2.setEndpoint(endPoint);

            HttpResponse res2 = h2.send(req2);

            system.debug(res2.getBody());

            deserializeResponse deresp=(deserializeResponse)System.JSON.deserialize(res2.getBody(),deserializeResponse.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the **mock**:

```
@isTest
global class SendOpportunityMock implements HttpCalloutMock {

    // Implement this interface method
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest request) {

        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        response.setBody('{"Name":"Test Opp Name","AccountId":"123456789123456789","CloseDate":"2018-02-28 00:00:00","StageName":"Prospecting"}');
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        return response; 
    }
}
```

Finally, the following is the **test** I have so far.  Included is commented-out code that would work *if* the future callout method - `createOpportunity` - could be given a return type.  However, future methods do not support return types:

```
@isTest
private class SendOpportunityTest {    

    @isTest static void testPostCallout() {

        Date d = date.valueOf('2017-12-13T12:38:43.000Z');        

        // Set mock callout class 
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new SendOpportunityMock()); 
        // This causes a fake response to be sent
        // from the class that implements HttpCalloutMock.
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account Name', External_Id__c = '123456789123456789');
        insert a;
        Opportunity o = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test Opp Name', AccountId = a.Id, CloseDate = d, StageName = 'Prospecting');        
        insert o;
        Test.starttest();
        SendOpportunity.createOpportunity('Test Opp Name', '123456789123456789', d, 'Prospecting');
        Test.stoptest();

 /*     HttpResponse response = SendOpportunity.createOpportunity();
        // Verify that the response received contains fake values
        String contentType = response.getHeader('Content-Type');
        System.assert(contentType == 'application/json');
        String actualValue = response.getBody();
        System.debug(response.getBody());
        String expectedValue = '{"Name":"Test Opp Name","AccountId":"123456789123456789","CloseDate":"2017-12-13T12:38:43.000Z","StageName":"Prospecting"}';
        System.assertEquals(actualValue, expectedValue);
        System.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode());  */
    }
}
```

A couple of additional details about my test so far:

- I tried `Test.starttest()` and `Test.stoptest()` because I read elsewhere that they could possibly be the solution.  But they don't solve the problem, at least not on their own.
- My trigger calls the `createOpportunity` method when an opportunity is created, so I inserted an opportunity - in addition to directly calling the method - just to cover the trigger.

I only achieve 63% coverage on the class when I run the test.  The pink lines in the screenshot below are the only ones that aren't covered:

[image]

Since the commented-out code in my test is the only variation I know and can find for testing REST callouts, I don't know how to proceed to achieve 100% coverage.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think issue is `ReturnAccessToken` method is also using callout, so you need to mock that callout.

After you mock that, then `accessToken` should not be null and hence you will get rest of code coverages.

Otherwise, you need to use this kind of logic in `createOpportunity` method.

```
if(Test.isRunningTest()){
    accessToken = 'Define your token';
}
if(accessToken!=null){

    //your existing webservice code.
}
```